# How can I get a Nexus 4 running 15.04 OTA-12 to connect to a particular wi-fi network when it won't accept the password

Tags: networking, 15.04, ubuntu-touch, nexus-4

After a fresh install the nexus 4 didn't even see any networks. Following other advice I downgraded the radio to something prior to 4.4 using

```
fastboot flash radio ~/Downloads/radio-mako-m9615a-cefwmazm-2.0.1700.33.img
```

After I rebooted I could see the network in my building but when I try to connect and enter the password it just doesn't do anything.  I originally thought it still had to do with the radio but I can connect to two other networks without problem.  I believe all 3 (one no-connect, two connect) are WPA.  Passwords formulas are as follows

Connect 1  - 10 numbers
Connect 2  - 6 Mixed case letters followed by 4 numbers
No Connect - 8 Mixed case letters, an underscore, 4 numbers

On the netork that won't connect, if I go in and change the wifi password (and don't touch anything else) it will connect fine.  I simply went to the wireless page, change the password temporarily to 10 numbers, clicked save, opened up the wifi on my phone and connected.  After that I went back to the original password (it is used by the whole company) and sure enough I can't connect.

Must this have something to do with the passwords, some kind of bug, or is there other information that I should provide or check?

UPDATE: Public wifi at a coffee shop works.  As far as I can tell it is just that password (or something about it) on one network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still researching the what, how, and why of this problem but I came across a bug that suggested copying and pasting the password https://bugs.launchpad.net/canonical-devices-system-image/+bug/1445630 which even though my password was far less complex than the one suggested, the answer worked.
So to be clear, I just copied the password from a note taking app and everything connected fine.